# LC tank circuit behavior

Tags: voltage, current, passive-networks, tank

Today in our lesson we did the LC tank circuit and its natural response frequency.I get how the equations work but what I didn't get is a qualitative explanation of what's going on.I mean why does the current behave the way it does the capacitor is fully discharged at T/4 of the oscillation?

[image]

Comment: Please show us a schematic and the waveforms that you are talking about.

Comment: The damping factor = 1/2Q for Q= gain by ratio of R/ X(fo) for parallel R and inversely for series resonant

Comment: I cannot post a schematic the circuit is bugged.

Comment: bugged ? the SE circuit editor or your lesson schematic ?

Comment: The SE circuit editor.I cant upload i will upload an image instead.

Comment: Add the figure of the current waveform with the `T/4` also highlighting the "behave the way it does". Remember to add the voltage waveform also.

Comment: You ask for *qualitative explanation* then state that you don't understand about T/4 (which would require a *quantitative explanation*). This makes me think I don't know what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For AC current ;  [a TANK circuit with an initial condition.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3AmArCA7NAbGAnKgHEhkqgrpMSEgMyWWSUCmAtGGAFADGIALN3j-178wCfvRjxIYbtllz5CkAmgy82bqipUikDH0g0JUtgHcQVBPT49r1yGwA25ywOf0RY8CCYSE07LrE-toGBFCmbuCiNsLR9twG4KgY3hbmkNzOUFAA%20no5kDkiSNQFsHBgZZAIVITqSHh8RHjkVHgFOQgdVDkAwmwJNGDJ4Bj0VBlKCJn0XfmFxdxIVRVVNXVLjXjNre2FXV09ADIDicMpeumZHtlz3B2LGHmwBGN4CB%20qeNsrUh0HOR6ADUAPYOAAuAEMAOYMNjQmJRQTWaQzcJAA)

- a Cap. is always leading sine voltage by 90 deg. so the current is 0 when voltage is either peak.
- an Inductor is always lagging sine voltage by 90 deg. so the current is also 0 when voltage is either peak.
- thus current is always 180 out of phase with voltage as charges flow out of Inductor into capacitor with the opposite polarity and visa versa.  At zero voltage, that Cap has no energy stored but the Inductor current has maximum peak energy stored, so energy swings back and forth in a sinusoidal shape.

Since this had some initial condition, it oscillates in theory forever.

- all electrical components have some resistance.
- Caps it's called ESR, effective series resistance (due to electrode interface) measured at some f, also related to Dissipation Factor, DF
- for inductors at DC so it's called DCR so there is always a limit for L/R

Is anything lossless? Not in electronics.

- electrons are lossless when oscillating in atomic orbit without excitation to escape orbit, then they become ions and there is a physical property change, but energy is neither created or destroyed.  So in conductors , caps and inductors it is converted to heat.